# Extending global object like `Autodesk.Viewing.Extension` with typescript support inside an ES6 module

Tags: typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have developed a forge extension and now I want to add typescript support following [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/typescript-definitions-forge-viewer-and-nodejs-client-sdk-now-available). However, I cannot extend the prototypes from the global Autodesk namespace like `Autodesk.Viewing.Extension`, `Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface` because typescript cannot find the objects `Cannot find name 'Autodesk'` (which don't exist at transpile time). Currently my workaround is to inject a the parameter `Autodesk` by calling a factory function which creates the Extension class (see code example) because I cannot access the global Autodesk variable from inside an ES6 module. This workaround removes all types naturally.

How can I fully support typescript in a custom extension?

#### My workaround

```js
function(Autodesk: any) { // injects Autodesk by passing the global accessible Autodesk object...
  return class MyExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
     ...
  };
}
```

#### What I want to achieve (with typescript support):

```js
class MyAwesomeExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
    }

    load() {
        console.log('MyAwesomeExtensions has been loaded');
        viewer.setEnvMapBackground(null); // Hide background environment if there is one
        viewer.setBackgroundColor(0, 64, 128); // Set background color
        return true;
    }

    unload() {
        console.log('MyAwesomeExtensions has been unloaded');
        return true;
    }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('MyAwesomeExtension', MyAwesomeExtension);
```

Comment: I broke down the problem to a typescript only question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028715/extending-a-class-unknown-at-transpile-time-with-correct-typescript-typings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my problem was that I didn't know how to access the global libraries from an ES6 module. However, you can use [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) to access global variables from inside an ES6 module. That enables you to use typings like normally.

MyExtension.ts

```js
const Autodesk = globalThis.Autodesk;
const THREE = globalThis.THREE;

export class MyExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
   //...
}
```

The first two lines (e.g. `const THREE = globalThis.THREE`) are not necessary if you configure typescript to allow umd access:

```
{ 
  "compilerOptions": {
      "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked for me. The hard part was getting google to find this answer in the first place.