# Autodesk + Angular: cannot find name autodesk

Tags: angular, typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am trying to add the forge viewer into my angular application. I have added the references to the head of my html files but it does not recognize Autodesk. I get the error: Cannot find name 'Autodesk'.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
</head>


<div id="forgeViewer"></div>
```

Here is the code from my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-forge-viewer',
  templateUrl: './forge-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forge-viewer.component.scss']
})
export class ForgeViewerComponent implements OnInit {

  
  private viewer= new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D();
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.initViewer();

  }
  private async initViewer() {

    var options = {
      env: 'AutodeskProduction',
      api: 'derivativeV2_EU', // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
      getAccessToken: null // get your 2 legged access token here instead of null (folow the turial)
    };

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {

      let htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer')
      let config3d = {

      }

      this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, config3d);

      var startedCode = this.viewer.start();
      if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
      }
      console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

    });
  }
}
```

I can not find a solution to this anywhere.

Has anyone come across this error before?

Many thanks,

Poppy

Comment: Have you seen this already? This issue must have been solved there somehow: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-adsk-forge-viewer

Comment: Sadly that code also didnt recognise Autodesk

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66012789/extending-global-object-like-autodesk-viewing-extension-with-typescript-suppor

Comment: Using globalThis.Autodesk seems to stop the error. I will see if I can get it working now. Thank you!

Comment: using Forge definition for typescript may solve your problem. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/typescript-definitions-forge-viewer-and-nodejs-client-sdk-now-available

Comment: Thank you! The solution that worked best for me was to run the links and scripts in the main index files. then run the forge html in its own component, and run the javascript in the component.ts file (changing it to typescipt myself) and by declaring:
 declare var document: any;
declare const Autodesk: any;
at the top of my typescipt file

Answer (score 4):

First:

```
npm i @types/forge-viewer -D
```

Then on top of your component file, add:

```
/// <reference types="forge-viewer" />
```